# Agrupar valores numa consulta PHP Mysql

Tags: php, sql, array

estou puxando valores do BD para uma tabela com os resultados da consulta, essa busca é por data, está funcionando perfeitamente se eu buscar para um único dia, porém eu gostaria de quando buscar para dois ou mais dias (ex 07/06/2018 a 08/06/2018), ele trouxesse os valores agrupados (compilados) dos dias da consulta, hoje ele trás os valores pulando as linhas e não agrupando eles;

código:

O sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reporte_producao WHERE data_reporte BETWEEN '$data_ida' AND '$data_volta' AND turno = '$turno' AND grupo = '$v' ORDER BY id ASC";
```

para gerar a tabela:

```
    foreach($num_array as $k => $v){

  ?>  
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $num_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $maq_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $grupo_arr[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $producao_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($producao_array[$k]) * 2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $segunda_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $terceira_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $producao_r_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($producao_r_array[$k])*2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $eficiencia_array[$k]."%"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } //fecha foreach
```

a maneira mais eficiênte de fazer isso seria abaixo? alguma sugestão?

```
$producao         += $data['producao'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer o group by pela data:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    reporte_producao
WHERE
    data_reporte BETWEEN '$data_ida'
AND '$data_volta'
AND turno = '$turno'
AND grupo = '$v'
GROUP BY
    date_format(data_reporte, '%d/%m/%Y')
ORDER BY
    id ASC
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno @Diego Souza, porém poderia explicar o que essa linha faz? sei que o GROUP BY agrupa, porém o que exatamente esse código é pra buscar?

Comment: Ele pega sua data, transforma em formato dd/mm/YYYY pra agrupar. Isso é necessário por causa do horário que provavelmente seu campo tem e é diferente. Daí não funcionaria o agrupamento.

Comment: não aparece nada na consulta;